# Error en sentencias switch case

Tags: java

Tengo este código y en el case 3 del switch hay un error y no se como solucionarlo . El codigo es en lenguaje java. Quiero que si un numero del array(o arreglo) álbum se repite que lo pase al array(o arreglo) repetidas

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean Salir=false,compra=false;
    String[]album=new String[669];//Album
    String []repetidas =new String[669];//Array de repetidas
    int sobresacomprar = 0;
    int []sobre=new int[5*sobresacomprar];//Sobre
    int i;

    for( i = 0 ; i < 669 ; i++){
    album[i]=" X ";
  }

  do{
                    System.out.println("");//Fines meramente estéticos
        System.out.println(""+"ªLas opciones que usted tiene son:ª");
        System.out.println("");//Fines meramente estéticos
                    System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println("1. Comprar Sobres");
        System.out.println("2. Figuritas faltantes");
        System.out.println("3. Figuritas repetidas");
        System.out.println("4. Salir");
                    System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println("");//Fines meramente estéticos
        System.out.println("Elija una opción:");
        byte op=entrada.nextByte();//Aquí termina el menú

switch(op){

case 1:

        compra=true;

        sobre=comprarsobres(sobresacomprar,sobre);

        guardarsobre(sobre,album);

      for( i=0;i<sobre.length;i++){//For recorre Array Sobre

            System.out.println(sobre[i]);  //muestra array Sobre

  }

break;

case 2:

     if(compra==false){//Se evalúa el boolean para ver si se ha realizado un sorteo
            System.out.println("Usted no ha hecho una compra todavía, por favor elija la opción 1 antes de listar.");//Dentro de esta condicional está el código a ejecutar si el usuario pretende listar las figuritas sin haber hecho una compra antes
break;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Sus figuritas faltantes son las: ");


        for(   i = 0 ; i < album.length ; i++ ){
           System.out.print(album[i]+" ");//Espacio entre los numeros
        if(i%36==000 && i!=0){
            System.out.println(" ");    
     }
 }              
}                            
break;

    case 3:

        if(compra==false){//Se evalúa el boolean para ver si se ha realizado un sorteo
            System.out.println("Usted no ha hecho una compra todavía, por favor elija la opción 1 antes de listar.");/*El código se ejecutara si el usuario 
                                                                                                                     pretende listar las figuritas sin haber 
                                                                                                                     hecho una compra antes*/
 break;
        }else{
            int result,z,cont=0;

            for( z=0;z<repetidas.length;z++){
                if(album[i].equals(repetidas[z])){
                   result=cont+1;
                    System.out.println(cont);
                }
            }
         }
 break;

 case 4:
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("Gracias por husar nuestro programa.");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("-=Creadores=-");
            System.out.println("Leandro Berni");
            System.out.println("Leandro Acosta");
            System.out.println(" ");
            Salir=true;/* Cuando el usuario digita el 4 se entra en este case, se muestra el mensaje de agradecimiento, 
                        y la variable booleana de salida pasa a ser true. Esto es muy importante, ya que si es true la 
                        variable, a la hora de evaluar en el do while, no se va a volver a ejecutar el menú*/
 break; 
}
  }while(Salir==false);/*Se vuelve a ejecutar el menú solamente si el usuario no ingresó 
                       en el case 4, si entra en el caso 4 el do while termina su ejecución y termina el programa.*/
}

public static int[] comprarsobres (int sobres,int [] sobre) { 

   Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("¡Bienvenido!¿Cuantos sobres desea comprar?");
    sobres=entrada.nextInt();
    sobre=new int[sobres*5];
         System.out.println("Sus figuritas son: ");

         int precio=25;
        System.out.println("Precio:"+"$"+precio*sobres);
        for(int i=0;i<sobre.length;i++){
            sobre[i]=(int)(Math.random()*669);
                System.out.println(sobre[i]);           
        }
   return sobre;
}

public static void guardarsobre(int[] sobre,String[] album){

    for(int i=0;i<sobre.length;i++){

       album[sobre[i]-1]=Integer.toString(sobre[i]);

    }
}

public static int figuritasrepetidas (int albumrepe) {

         System.out.println("Sus figuritas repetidas son las: ");
    return 0;


}          


}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que tipo de error tira? podrias decirnos en que linea?

Comment: en la linea 83.

Comment: me da un error asi : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 669
 at proyecto.programación.album.ProyectoProgramaciónAlbum.main(ProyectoProgramaciónAlbum.java:84)
C:\Users\Miguel\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1

Comment: SIEMPRE, el error debe ir en la pregunta, asi como la linea donde se produce. Una pared de codigo es dificil de seguir y hace muy dificil ayudarte. Presiona [edit] y agrega el error y la informacion en la pregunta. Igual el error es claro, estas tratando de acceder a un elemento del array que no existe, porque te pasaste del largo...

Comment: ah y no tenemos ni idea cual es la linea 83...

Comment: la line 83 es esta: for( z=0;z<repetidas.length;z++){
                if(album[i].equals(repetidas[z])){
                   result=cont+1;
                    System.out.println(cont);

Comment: Todo en la pregunta debe ir, no en comentarios!

Comment: y el error es claro.. que es i ahi adentro??? a que i te referis?

Comment: no se como editar la pregunta la i es un numero que de el array album

Comment: Te lo dije, presiona el boton [edit] y te permite editar tu pregunta. editar esta justo debajo de tu pregunta. a la izquierda de tu avatar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola no entiendo muy bien pero

```
         int z ;
 int cont =0 ;

    for(i=0;i<album.length-1;i++){
        cont = 0;
            for(int j=i+1;j<album.length;j++){

                if(album[i]==album[j]){
                    cont++;
                }
            }
             System.out.println("Elemento repetido: album posicion " +i + " tiene " + album[i] + " se repite  "  + cont + " veces" );
        }
```

Comment: Quiero que si un numero del array álbum se repite que lo pase al array repetidas

Comment: revisa .. he modificado . espero que sea tu duda

Comment: esto sufre el problema de contar repetidas por duplicado. si album[i] == album[j], entonces cuando album[j] == album[i].. o sea si el elemento 1 = 2, entonces el elemento 2=1 y lo contaste 2 veces

Comment: en eso me muestra tambien en donde no hay numero que es la X y yo quiero que me muestre solo donde hay un numero ,osea que no me cuente las X

Comment: pues hombre ,,, solo valida si el texto del arreglo album es entero   try {
                int foo = Integer.parseInt(album[i]);

} catch (NumberFormatException e) {

}